# Can't post to user's wall, though I get publish_stream permission

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm implementing an app which will post to user's wall.

I specify appropriate scopes (including publish_stream) via php-sdk, display the authentication page and can confirm that my app requires publish_stream. But when the app tries to post to user wall, I get the following error message:

The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action

Also, my app cannot get  public_stream permission when I confirm the app from user's privacy setting.

I could confirm that my app's authentication of publish_stream worked well one weeks ago.

Are there any problem regarding publish_stream permission?

Answer (score 0):

fb in your app insight to see if your app is restricted for publishing stream